# AWS glue: how to execute stored procedure in SQL Server and get data from its result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, aws-glue

I can only execute the stored procedure, but not get what it returns.

It only returns the value true.

Call stored procedure on dbeaver.
[Imagen del stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfNVg.png)

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.Connection")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.DatabaseMetaData")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.DriverManager")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.SQLException")

print('Trying to connect to DB')
source_jdbc_conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf('sgc_con')
conn = sc._gateway.jvm.DriverManager.getConnection(source_jdbc_conf.get('url'), source_jdbc_conf.get('user'), source_jdbc_conf.get('password'))
print('Trying to connect to DB success!')
print(conn.getMetaData())
print('prepareCall')
statement = "EXEC MNA.dbo.zz_MNAvArticulosListar"
exec_statement = conn.prepareCall(statement)
print('execute')
rs = exec_statement.execute()
print(rs) #true
exec_statement.close()
```

So far I can only connect to SQL Server and execute the stored procedure

Comment: If you need a result set have you considered [executeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) instead?

Comment: I made the change to
rs = statement.executeQuery();

I can get the data
rs.next()
print("ID: "+rs.getString("Id")+", ")

But I don't know the syntax to traverse and pass to a dataframe

Comment: I generate a list to add each of the fields.
`data = []`
`while rs.next():`
`data.append((rs.getString("Id"),rs.getString("IdArticulo"),rs.getString("Referencia"),rs.getString("Descripcion")))`

Comment: I have to see how to get the headers from: `rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(x)`

Comment: resolved loop get columns:

columnsNamme = []
i = 0;
`for i in range(rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()):
    columnsNamme.append(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1))`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I can get the data returned by a SQL Server stored procedure, executed from
AWS glue.

I will continue working on leaving the job without writing the names of the columns, so that they are obtained dynamically.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.types import *

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.Connection")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.DatabaseMetaData")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.DriverManager")
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"java.sql.SQLException")

#Creates Empty RDD
emptyRDD = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
print(emptyRDD)

# Defining the schema of the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
  StructField('Id', StringType(), True),
  StructField('IdArticulo', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Referencia', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Descripcion', StringType(), True)
  ])
 
#Create empty DataFrame from empty RDD
df = spark.createDataFrame(emptyRDD,schema)
df.printSchema()

#Create list columns list
columns = ['Id', 'IdArticulo', 'Referencia', 'Descripcion']

print('Trying to connect to DB')
source_jdbc_conf = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf('sgc_con')
con = sc._gateway.jvm.DriverManager.getConnection(source_jdbc_conf.get('url'), source_jdbc_conf.get('user'), source_jdbc_conf.get('password'))
print('Trying to connect to DB success!')
print(con.getMetaData())
print('prepareCall')
stmt = con.prepareStatement("EXEC MNA.dbo.zz_MNAvArticulosListar");
#Execute query - stored procedure
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
print(rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount())

#get columns name
columnsNamme = []
i = 0;
for i in range(rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()):
    columnsNamme.append(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1))

print(columnsNamme)

#get data result from stored procedure
data = []
while rs.next():
    data.append((rs.getString("Id"),rs.getString("IdArticulo"),rs.getString("Referencia"),rs.getString("Descripcion")))

print(data)

#Create final dataframe
second_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
second_df.show()

#pending obtain columns and data dynamically, to generate a generic job.

rs.close()
stmt.close()
```

[Image of the output data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBddB.png)